# Is it possible for multipleparams in C# 7?

Tags: c#, parameters, tuples, c#-7.2

I want to do something like this:

```
public void PrintIDs(params int[] IDs, params string[] names) 
{ 
    // Throw error if arrays aren't same size 

    for (int i = 0; i = IDs.Length; i++) 
        Console.WriteLine($"{names[i]}: {IDs[i]}"); 
} 


... 

PrintIDs(player.ID, "Player ID", computer.ID, "Computer ID"); 
PrintIDs(sword1.ID, "Sword 1 ID", sword2.ID, "Sword 2 ID");
```

But I get an error saying: `A params parameter must be the last parameter in the list`. I could just use a single `params object[]` but that looses compiler and IDE support and type safety. Anyway to do this?

Comment: Your sample code has a problem because you aren't enforcing that `IDs` and `names` have the same length. If the client passes more `IDs` than `names`, then you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: Also, your sample is passing in a mixed set of args (int string int string...), while the method is expecting all ints followed by all strings.

Comment: > `Throw error if arrays aren't the same size` I put that comment there because I would handle that issue later, but I removed it to keep the code more simple. I know this code doesn't work, it's just an example to show the functionality I wanted there to be.

Comment: Oh, i missed that!

Comment: All good, haha.

Comment: You don't need the `params` keyword or tuples to pass a list or `IEnumerable` of items to a method. You don't need *tuples* if you want to pass items in a parameter list. Just specify an array of the item's type. This looks like a question trying to fit an answer

Comment: I know you don't need those, like you also don't need properties, you *could* just use methods, and you don't *need* auto-properties either, but this is the easiest way to get that result, so why not use it? I'm not going to do some array creation as an argument. Why do `PrintIDs(new int[] { 1, 5, 7,}, new string[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz") });` when I can just do `PrintIDs((1, "Foo), (5, "Bar"), (7, "Baz"));` and always gaurentee that the arrays will be the same size and have them assoicated together as one unit?

Comment: I just discovered how to do something that I knew other people wanted to do, so I just thought I'd share it.

Answer (score 4):

Using C# 7's `System.ValueTuple`, you can do this:

```
public void PrintIDs(params (int ID, string name)[] namedIDs) 
{ 
    foreach (var namedID in namedIDs) 
       Console.WriteLine($"{namedID.name}: {namedID.ID}); 
}
```

Or, to be cleaner:

```
public void PrintIDs(params (int ID, string name)[] namedIDs) 
{ 
    foreach (var (ID, name) in namedIDs) 
        Console.WriteLine($"{name}: {ID}); 
}
```

And if you liked having them as two separate ways, you can use an extension method like this:

```
public static (T1[] array1, T2[] array2) SplitToArrays<T1,T2>(this (T1 t1, T2 t2)[] tuples)
{ 
    var array1 = new T1[tuples.Length]; 
    var array2 = new T2[tuples.Length]; 

    foreach (var (i, tuple) in tuples.Index())
        array1[i] = tuple.t1; array2[i] = tuple.t2; 

    return (array1, array2); 
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
public void PrintIDs(params (int ID, string name)[] namedIDs) 
{ 
   (int[] IDs, string[] names) = namedIDs.SplitToArrays(); 

   // OR: 

   var (IDs, names) = namedIDs.SplitToArrays(); 
   for (int i = 0; i = obj.Length; i++) 
        Console.WriteLine($"{names[i]}: {IDs[i]}"); 
}
```

Either way, you'll call it like so:

```
PrintIDs((player.ID, "Player ID"), (computer.ID, "Computer ID")); 
PrintIDs((sword1.ID, "Sword 1 ID"), (sword2.ID, "Sword 2 ID"));
```

The cool thing to is that they'll have to be the same size, which in my experience is how I wanted them anyways. If you want them different sizes, you could probably just do something like `(player.ID, null)` or `(player.ID, default)` and then do the proper `null` or `default` checking to make it so the arrays are two different sizes, using `int?` instead of `int`, etc.

Comment: Why not use `IEnumerable<(int ID, string name)>`?  You don't get a whole lot of benefit with `params` here...

Comment: Because then, instead of simply, `PrintIDs((3, "foo");`, I'd have to do, `PrintIDs(new List<int, string>() { (3, "foo");`. Why would I type that much if I don't need too? I don't see what other benefit I'm getting from using `IEnumerable<>`. The whole point of `param` is to let us add more arguments of the same type easily without having to create a new `IEnumerable<>` as an arguement.

Comment: @AustinWBryan Actually `PrintIds(new [] {(3, "foo"),(2, "bar")})` would work, but I agree there's no benefit to switch.

Comment: @juharr Right, I forgot about that, but even then, you're getting an array, so that is literally exactly the same result as `params`. At least if you use the `List<>` you're getting a list instead which is functionally different from `params`,  seeing as `params List<int> numbers` is invalid.